# Place text as background to table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a word as a background to a table and have it span the height and width of the table. I can place the text in the table div with a height and width of 100% but it does not span the height and width? [Here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/oNNPNMK?editors=1100) is my codepen of what I am trying to do. Thank you.

CSS

```
#background-text {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #52a94c;
}
```

Comment: well the font size is not going to be dynamic.

Comment: you need to add font size to the text and opacity if you want that text to look faded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some options:

First, is trying to use vw, but you will need to use media-queries for multiple sizes. Eg:

```
font-size: 17vw;
```

Another better option is using Javascript libraries like:

http://fittextjs.com/ (with jquery)

https://github.com/adactio/FitText.js (without jquery)

Here is a simple example using [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/):

```
$("div").fitText(0.38);
```

It will make the text fit 38% percent of the div.

[EDIT] Here is a more complete article with some techniques to fit the text: https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

Answer (score 0):

You are just modifying the element. If you want the text to also change size, you need to set the font size.

```
font-size: 100vh;
```